# 2D slicing confusion

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a two dimensional `numpy` array. For example:

```
dog = np.random.rand(3, 3)
```

Now, I can extract the intersection of the first and second row and the second and third column of dog thus:

```
dog[:2, 1:]
```

I can also do

```
dog[[0, 1], 1:]
```

or

```
dog[:2, [1, 2]]
```

But I **CAN NOT** do

```
dog[[0, 1], [1, 2]]
```

That returns a one dimensional array of the `[0, 1]` and `[1, 2]` elements of `dog`.
And this seems to mean that to extract that principal submatrix which is the intersection of the first and last row of `dog` and the first and last column I have to something gross like:

```
tmp = dog[[0, 2], :]
ans = tmp[:, [0, 2]]
```

Is there some more civilized way extracting submatrices? The obvious solution `dog[[0, 2], [0, 2]]` does work in **Julia**.

Comment: [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html)

Comment: @PaulPanzer Does work, thanks, but still seems a little barbarous :)

Comment: A small price to pay for massively more expressive power. I don't know Julia but going by your example all you can address are rectangular subselections. `numpy` syntax can address any subset (and repeated elements if needed),

Comment: @PaulPanzer a fundamental design principle is to make simple things easy. Arguably the python design fails on those grounds. Super-complicated schemes with much expressive powers appear in julia as well. How many people use them in either language I don't know. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/subarrays/

Comment: At some point it is easier to just write a program - one reason why many of us have a soft spot for C in our hearts.

Comment: I'm the last person to deny that python/numpy have their fair share of warts. But this is not one of them. On the contrary, as long as you are not mixing traditional and advanced indexing (which is indeed awkward) it strikes as perfect a balance between power and simplicity as you will ever see. (All comes down to [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) which is simple and logical.) Btw.  for your last example you could use traditional indexing: `dog[::2,::2]`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yes, I know. I was trying to make a small simple example., but it was not quite perfect. As for numpy perfection, maybe, but I am assuming (but correct me if I am wrong) the underscore at the end of `ix_` indicates to me that this is meant to be some sort of an "advanced" feature that is not guaranteed to survive... Is this correct?

Comment: To be honest I never thought too deeply about this. I am, however, pretty sure it does not mean the feature is unstable. numpy does afaik have a quite disciplined deprecation policy with ample (and explicit) warning. My take is the following: numpy it feels to me is a 1.5th class citizen in Python, so core developers will not normally consider changing the interpreter for it. Afaik they did to permit indexing by tuples (aka nd indexing) but that's about it. `ix_` along with `r_`, `c_` and `s_` is part of the `index_tricks` submodule which to me is a collection of stuff tgat really should have

Comment: its own syntax but can't for the above reason. The trailing underline I interpret as a have your cake and eat it: make the name as short as possible but without polluting namespace too much. I should stress that this is not based on any research, just an educated guess.

Comment: Correction: indexing by tuples would be required by dicts, as well, so not a numpy concession. I mixed something up there. What I remembered wrongly is [PEP 357 -- Allowing Any Object to be Used for Slicing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/) Not sure about tuples of slices which seems numpy specific, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [94]: dog = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [95]: dog
Out[95]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

the slice block:

```
In [96]: dog[:2,1:]
Out[96]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

With 2 lists (1d arrays), we select the diagonal from that block:

```
In [97]: dog[[0,1],[1,2]]
Out[97]: array([1, 5])
```

But if we change the first to (2,1) array, it broadcasts with the (2,) to select at (2,2) block:

```
In [98]: dog[[[0],[1]],[1,2]]
Out[98]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])

In [99]: dog[np.ix_([0,1],[1,2])]
Out[99]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```

`ix_` turns the 2 lists into (2,1) and (1,2) arrays:

```
In [100]: np.ix_([0,1],[1,2])
Out[100]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[1, 2]]))
```

The diagonal selection in [97] follows the same logic: `(2,) and (2,) => (2,)`

I don't know about Julia, but MATLAB lets us use [97] like syntax to select the block, but to get the 'diagonal' we have to convert the indices to a flat index, the equivalent of:

```
In [104]: np.ravel_multi_index(([0,1],[1,2]),(3,3))
Out[104]: array([1, 5])
In [105]: dog.flat[_]
Out[105]: array([1, 5])
```

So what's easy in `numpy` is harder in MATLAB, and visa versa.  Once you understand broadcasting the `numpy` approach is logical and general.